# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of interface jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep is named Publisher

Tags: java, jenkins, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running Jenkins on GKE, migrating from VM. I am getting this error in one of the gradlew test builds. Anyone has any idea on how to approach it?

```
Error when executing always post condition:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {delegate={$class=Publisher, reportFilenamePattern=**/testng-results.xml}} for org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of interface jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep is named Publisher


Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of interface jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep is named Publisher
```

Comment: What is the version of Jenkins?

Comment: It looks like it may be related with different versions of some jenkins plugins implemented on GKE and on your VM. This one looks similar: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-56160

Comment: What GKE and Jenkins version are you using? It might be related with some versions mismatch, did you try newest versions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what was solution to this, but most of issues I had were solved by installing plugins in newer version, and all their dependent plugins

Comment: Since your issue is resolved please accept the solution you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to the lack of the TestNG plugin. The install/update of the plugin must have been the solution. [Here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/INFRA-20715) you can see a case with the same output solved by installing TestNG plugin.